# How to scroll RecyclerView to top after new data is fetched from network; I am using ListAdapter, DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I am using `ListAdapter` to update `RecyclerView`.

My Adapter Looks like

```
class MyListAdapter<T, VH : ViewHolder>() :
        ListAdapter<T, VH>(MyDiffUtilItemCallback()) {
...
...
Adapter code
...
...


class MyDiffUtilItemCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {

  override fun areItemsTheSame(
    oldItem: Product?,
    newItem: Product?
  ): Boolean {
    if (oldItem != null && newItem != null) {
      return oldItem.productId == newItem.productId
    }
    return false
  }

  override fun areContentsTheSame(
    oldItem: Product?,
    newItem: Product?
  ): Boolean {
    if (oldItem != null && newItem != null) {
      return oldItem.productId == newItem.productId && 
                 oldItem.name== newItem.name && oldItem.weight == newItem.weight
    }
    return false
  }
}
}
```

I am implementing google like search where user can enter search query and when user pauses API is called for that query and `RecyclerView` is updated with result. Now if user appends to query again data is fetched and added to `RecyclerView`. Here I want `RecyclerView` scroll to top position.

Following code code is not working for me:

```
productAdapter.submitList(productList)
rvBillingProduct.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

As difference is getting calculated on background thread `rvBillingProduct.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` is getting executed before data is being added to list.

I am not sure how to get callback when DiffUtils result calculation is complete so that I can scroll `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

`ListAdapter` does not provide methods to let you know when the diff has finished computing. You can use `PagedListAdapter` instead and use `submitList(myList, callback)` or override `onCurrentListChanged(...)` method in the adapter:

```
class MyListAdapter<T, VH : ViewHolder>() :
        PagedListAdapter<T, VH>(MyDiffUtilItemCallback()) {

    ...

    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: PagedList<T>, currentList: PagedList<T>) {
         // Called when the current PagedList is updated.
    }
}
```